# burp suite cannot open

Tags: java, burp

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : burploader.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed Agent_OnLoad: instrument

I am now JAVA 21 version, windows 11.